# Getting Corrupted Content Error with iTextSharp PDF and Firefox: does not work with Firefox 10.xx

Tags: .net, firefox, pdf, itext

I have a dynamic PDF form that is populated and flattened out.
This PDF works and shows up correctly with IE on any version.
With Firefox I get this error:

> Corrupted Content Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Can anyone please help me out why I am getting this error and what the fix needs to be without breaking my functional IE PDF code.

Comment: Can't remember exactly what minor version, but I had the same problem on one of the automatic updates. I think the update screwed up the PDF application mapping. Had to manually re-add the mapping to open PDFw/Adobe Reader. Another thing that worked was adding the `Content-Disposition` header to mark the PDF as a file attachment, but not sure if you want to go there...

Comment: What do the HTTP headers your server sends look like?

Comment: This is how the PDF is output to browser.  private void writeOutputStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            //using (MemoryStream stream = GeneratePDF(m_FormsPath, oXmlData))
            //{
                byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.End();
            //}
        }

Comment: private const string PDF_EXT = ".pdf";
        private const string PDF_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/pdf";
      public static void setHttpHeaders(System.Web.HttpResponse response
            ,
                String contentType, String fileName, String extension, int size,
                bool isInline)
        {
            response.ContentType = contentType;
            response.AddHeader(CONTENT_DISP_HEADER,
                    getContentDispositionString(fileName, extension, isInline));
        }

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In Firefox 11.0, I'd get "Corrupted Content Error", but it would deliver the PDF fine in other browsers.

The problem was simply that I had set the `Content-Disposition` header *twice* in my code. Firefox is apparently picky about this (or has recently become so). Once I got rid of the duplicate header setting, it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  In MVC, especially, this is important to know, because MVC itself will set the Content-Disposition automatically when returning a FileContentResult.

Comment: Is there a way to make MVC not do that? I want to specify content-disposition as inline but keep running into this duplicate header error. It seems to default to attachment.

Answer (score 0):

By Adding this before last time when using AddHeader Method will give the Solution.

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
```